# K8s - Unable to reach application from outside the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I am learning to deploy applications on private clusters. The application is up and running in a pod and is reachable from the node itself. I have created an ingress controller service as well, but I am not sure what's going wrong. The external IP of the nginx-ingress service always returns 404. Any ideas on the fix ?

Services running :

[image]

Application service :

[image]

Nginx service :

[image]

Application ingress :

[image]

Ingress yaml :
[image]

Comment: Can you share the YAML file of your ingress object?

Comment: @KamolHasan Added to the question

Comment: Could you check the logs of the Nginx pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Ingress is not being served by your Nginx Ingress controller at the moment. If the Ingress is served by a controller, it should have at least one IP Address under its `status.loadBalancer` (which should be the external IP used by the Ingress Controller which is serving it), while in your case, looks empty like this:

```
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

The most common problem on this regard is that the Ingress does not define an Ingress Class or there is no default Ingress Class in the cluster.

First of all, do a `k get IngressClass` and see if there's any Ingress Class defined. in your cluster. **Depending on the Kubernetes version and Ingress Controller version**, it could make use of IngressClass objects or simply use annotations (or both).

I would try simply adding the annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` under the Ingress `metadata` as the nginx class is usually the one defined by the Nginx Ingress Controller. Or, if your Ingress Controller is using a different Ingress Class, I'd try specify that in the annotation, then your setup **should** work.

---

If you are curious on what is the purpose of an Ingress Class, it can mostly be used to associate an Ingress resource definition, with an ingress controller. On a Kubernetes cluster, there may be more than one Ingress Controller, each one with its own ingress class and Ingress resources are associated to one of them by matching the requested ingress class.

If an ingress class is not specified, the Ingress uses the default one, which means that the IngressClass annotated to be the default one of the cluster is automatically used.

For more info, check the documentation here ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-class )

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-19-82 service]$ kubectl get IngressClass
NAME    CONTROLLER                     PARAMETERS   AGE
nginx   nginx.org/ingress-controller   <none>       25h

Is that how it's supposed to be ?

Comment: Can you describe it, to see if its annotated to be the default one in the cluster? Did you try add `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` as an annotation in your Ingress definition, (together with the body size which you already specified) ?

Comment: I did. then I tried the curl -I -H "Host: vv2ta3ox.mx-demo" a6ac7...........eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/ command to get

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.8
Date: Sat, 24 Apr 2021 12:05:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 8597
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Fri, 24 Apr 2020 12:05:35 UTC
Last-Modified: Sat, 24 Apr 2021 10:22:43 UTC

That is a good sign I hope. But I still am missing on how to access the app via browser :|

Comment: Your ingress is serving your service under /, what do you receive when you open the url on the browser?

Comment: a simple call to the URL returns 404. But if use the extension ModHeader to add a header to the browser - Host: vv2ta3ox.mx-demo. It works.

Comment: I see, if you remove the host from the Ingress definition, the service will be served and available at the IP adress directly. If you want to use the host instead, you should make it point to the Nginx Ingress Controller IP either with a DNS A record (for a valid host you own) or simply on your machine, associate the IP to the host (for example on hosts file) and then you can go directly on vv2ta3ox.mx-demo on your browser.